# Python: Filter Empty Strings From Multiple List of Dictionaries

Tags: python

May I know how can I come up with my expected result. I'm struggling this for an hour using “if” statement but nothing happened.

```
books = [{'title':'Angels and Demons'},{'title':''},{'title':'If'},{'title':'Eden'}]
authors = [{'author':'Dan Brown'},{'author':'Veronica Roth'},{'author':''},{'author':'James Rollins'}]

for i, book in enumerate(books):
    print(book, authors[i])
```

---

```
expected result:
({'title': 'Angels and Demons'}, {'author': 'Dan Brown'})
({'title': 'Eden'}, {'author': 'James Rollins'})
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even have an if statement. How can we help you if you don't explain properly? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want might be exclude the pair which the title or the author is empty string.

```
books = [{'title':'Angels and Demons'},{'title':''},{'title':'If'},{'title':'Eden'}]
authors = [{'author':'Dan Brown'},{'author':'Veronica Roth'},{'author':''},{'author':'James Rollins'}]

for book, author in zip(books, authors):
    if book["title"] and author["author"]:
        print(book, author)

# or 

[(book, author) for book, author in zip(books, authors) if book["title"] and author["author"]]
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using List Comphersion

```
 [(books[i],authors[i]) for i,v in enumerate(books) if books[i]['title']  and authors[i]['author']]
```

**Output**:

```
 [({'title': 'Angels and Demons'}, {'author': 'Dan Brown'}), ({'title': 'Eden'}, {'author': 'James Rollins'})]
```

Answer (score 1):

One line code for your problem

```
In [3]: [(book, author) for book, author in zip(books,authors) if book['title'] and author['author']]
Out[3]: 
[({'title': 'Angels and Demons'}, {'author': 'Dan Brown'}),
 ({'title': 'Eden'}, {'author': 'James Rollins'})]
```

Comment: you can use `generator` if there are lots of values, for memory better optimisation.

Answer (score -1):

```
books = [{'title':'Angels and Demons'},{'title':''},{'title':'If'},{'title':'Eden'}]
authors = [{'author':'Dan Brown'},{'author':'Veronica Roth'},{'author':''},{'author':'James Rollins'}]

for i, book in enumerate(books):
    if book['title'] != '':
        print(book, authors[i])
```

This should work